# Angular formGroup inside formArray, formGroup is invalid, but `formArray.valid` is true

Tags: angular, angular-forms, angular-formbuilder

this is my primary code:

```js
get emailFormArray() {
  return this.formGroup.get("emails") as FormArray;
}

public ngOnInit() {
  this.formGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
    emails: this.formBuilder.array([]),
  });
  this.addEmailFormGroup();
}

public addEmailFormGroup() {
  this.emailFormArray.controls.push(
    this.formBuilder.group({
      email: ['', Validators.email],
    }),
  );
}
```

and in my template

```html
{{ formGroup.valid }}
{{ emailFormArray.valid }}
<ng-container *ngFor="let email of emailFormArray.controls">
  {{ email.valid }}
  {{ email.get('email').valid }}
</ng-container>
```

When I input a invalid email, the result in template is `true true false false`, why the `formGroup` and `emailFormArray` is valid? Thank you!

Comment: Off Topic - You can omit `public` from `public ngOnInit`

Comment: Yes thank yout, but I prefer this code style

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I found the reason.
I should use `this.emailFormArray.push` instead of `this.emailFormArray.controls.push`

Comment: Even I was about to post to the same answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue when load data from database and update data, it did not keep validation rule. The problem that I set direct value to form control as

```
loadSlideItemFromDB(slideShowItem): FormArray {
    const formArray = new FormArray([]);
    slideShowItem.forEach(item => {
      formArray.push(this.fb.group({
        id: item.Id,
        slideShowId: item.SlideShowId,
        pageType: item.PageType,
        linkUrl: item.LinkUrl,
        pageTitle: item.PageTitle
      }))
    });

    return formArray;
  }
```

After refactoring code, I create form array with validation rule first and then `patchValue` for it.

I share this for whom concerned.

```
loadSlideItemFromDB(slideShowItem): FormArray {
    const formArray = new FormArray([]);
    slideShowItem.forEach(item => {
      let group = this.fb.group({
        id: [''],
        slideShowId: [''],      
        pageType: ['1', Validators.required],
        linkUrl: ['', Validators.required],
        pageTitle: ['']
      })
      group.patchValue({
        id: item.Id,
        slideShowId: item.SlideShowId,
        pageType: item.PageType,
        linkUrl: item.LinkUrl,
        pageTitle: item.PageTitle
      });
      formArray.push(group);
    });

    return formArray;
  }
```